# Bash echo output redirected to log file in specified directory

Tags: bash, redirect, curl, echo

I'm getting the both right results but I'm also getting a additional weird result.  A file is being created for each file that I'm downloading in the directory of script being executed and not in to log directory.   When I commented the echo out, it goes away and the files are not created. Is there another way or what is the correct way for me to log the address that I'm downloading into CURL?

```
echo $DLADDR$'\r' >> Downloads/LOGS/$LOGFILE 2>$1
curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR >> Downloads/LOGS/$LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change that `2>$1` into `2>&1`.  Otherwise stderr will be redirected into a file of the name `"$1"` (first argument to the script).

Comment: Thank you that was an oversight!